# Slides, transição de imagens com JS e radio, ao encostar o mouse em cima da imagem pausar a transição, ao retirar continuar a transição

Tags: javascript, html, css, radiobutton

```js
 onload  = start;

function start(){ 
var i = 1;
function Move(){  
 i = (i%3)+1; // 4 is the Number of image in slider
 document.getElementById('t'+i).checked = true;
}
setInterval(Move,3000); //change img in 3 sec
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:#0066FF;}

.ct{ 
 position:relative; 
 width:400px; 
 height:220px; 
 margin:auto; 
 border:2px solid #000; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
input{ display:none;}

.img_s{ position:absolute; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 z-index:-1; 
 font-size:25px;
 text-align:center;
}

.im1, .im2, .im3{ position:relative; width:400px; 
 height:225px;
}

.pre, .nxt{ position:absolute;
 width:12%;
 height:100%;
 top:0;
 background:rgba(88,88,88,.4);
 z-index:99;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:30px;
}
p{ position:relative; top:50px;
}
.pre{ left:0; 
}
.nxt{ right:0; 
}
.cr{ width:100%;
 height:11px;
 bottom:12px;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:99;
}
.dts{ position: relative; 
 display: inline-block;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
 
#t1:checked ~ #one,
#t2:checked ~ #two,
#t3:checked ~ #three{
 z-index:99; transition:all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ct">
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t1" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t2"/>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t3"/>

<div class="img_s" id="one">
   <div class="im1" style="background-color: #FFF;">01-IMG</div>
   <label for="t3" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
   <label for="t2" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
</div>

<div class="img_s" id="two">
   <div class="im2" style="background-color:#0C3;">02-IMG</div>
   <label for="t1" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
   <label for="t3" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
</div>

<div class="img_s" id="three">
   <div class="im3" style="background-color:#F63;">03-IMG</div>
   <label for="t2" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
   <label for="t1" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
</div>



</div>
```

Tenho um pequeno slide, que funciona com radios e transição em JS. O código ao todo funciona normal, só que eu pretendo incrementar no javascript que ao encostar o mouse em cima dentro da caixa de slide a transição JS dos radios pause dando a chance do usuário clicar nas setas laterais e selecionar as imagens e ao retirar o mouse de dentro da caixa a transição continue normalmente, seria possível incrementar com esse simples código em javascript essas funções?? tentei aqui e não tive sucesso, ?

Comment: Salve o valor retornado pela função `setInterval`, em uma variável. Após isso basta utilizar os métodos `mouseenter` e `mouseleave` para detectar quando o mouse está, ou não, sobre o *slider*. Feito isso basta utilizar [**clearInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) ou usar o este exemplo como base https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278007/9101590

Comment: Eu tentei fazer com keyframes ao invés de utilizar esse JS, mas não deu certo, porém eu ainda sou bastante leigo em JS

Comment: Tem comandos que eu não conheço em JS e dificulta bastante, provavelmente eu não vou acerta kkkk, mas obrigado pela informação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separei a variavel i e a função move de dentro da função start, adicionei value para os radios para facilitar a identificação de onde está o slider corrente.
Armazena o identificador do setInterval, necessário para parar o setInterval.
Adicionei um id na div do slider apenas para facilitar a atribuição dos eventos, mouseenter para parar o slider automático e mouseleave para reiniciar o slider automático.

```js
onload  = start;
var intervalId;
var i = 1;
function Move(){  
   i = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="tabs"]:checked').value, 10) + 1;
   if(i > document.getElementsByName('tabs').length) {
    i = 1;
   }
  document.getElementById('t'+i).checked = true;
}
function start(){  
 intervalId = setInterval(Move,3000); //change img in 3 sec
}
function stop(){
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
slider.addEventListener('mouseenter', stop);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', start);
```

```css
body{ background-color:#0066FF;}

.ct{ 
 position:relative; 
 width:400px; 
 height:220px; 
 margin:auto; 
 border:2px solid #000; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
input{ display:none;}

.img_s{ position:absolute; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 z-index:-1; 
 font-size:25px;
 text-align:center;
}

.im1, .im2, .im3{ position:relative; width:400px; 
 height:225px;
}

.pre, .nxt{ position:absolute;
 width:12%;
 height:100%;
 top:0;
 background:rgba(88,88,88,.4);
 z-index:99;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:30px;
}
p{ position:relative; top:50px;
}
.pre{ left:0; 
}
.nxt{ right:0; 
}
.cr{ width:100%;
 height:11px;
 bottom:12px;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:99;
}
.dts{ position: relative; 
 display: inline-block;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
 
#t1:checked ~ #one,
#t2:checked ~ #two,
#t3:checked ~ #three{
 z-index:99; transition:all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="ct" id="slider">
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t1" value="1" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t2" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t3" value="3"/>

<div class="img_s" id="one">
   <div class="im1" style="background-color: #FFF;">01-IMG</div>
   <label for="t3" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
   <label for="t2" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
</div>

<div class="img_s" id="two">
   <div class="im2" style="background-color:#0C3;">02-IMG</div>
   <label for="t1" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
   <label for="t3" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
</div>

<div class="img_s" id="three">
   <div class="im3" style="background-color:#F63;">03-IMG</div>
   <label for="t2" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
   <label for="t1" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
</div>



</div>
```

Comment: Ficou ótimo! mas caso eu queira adicionar mais imagens, eu preciso mudar o  .value, 10) + 1; ?

Comment: no caso aí vai até dez? estou correto?

Comment: se passar de 10 radios eu apenas incremento mais valores, correto?

Comment: @ElienayJunior O `10` é apenas uma base (indica que os valores retornados por `parseInt` **deve** ser decimal). Ps.: O valor `10` é opcional. Caso você queira adicionar mais imagens, não é necessário modificar o *JavaScript*.

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de usar `class="ct"` seria mais interessante usar `id="ct"` se o elemento for único. Assim fica mais fácil selecionar ele:

```
#ct{ 
 position:relative; 
 width:400px; 
 height:220px; 
 margin:auto; 
 border:2px solid #000; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Em seguida pode criar eventos para parar a transição quando o mouse estiver sobre a `div`, inclusive precisará parar a transição no clique nas setas porque ao clicar o evento `mouseleave` é chamado, fazendo com que a transição continua mesmo estando com o mouse sobre o slider.

Também tem que atribuir o `setInterval` à uma variável para poder controlá-lo:

```
timer = setInterval(Move,3000);
```

O código bem otimizado ficaria desta forma, sem muitos arrodeios:

```js
var timer;
var slider = document.querySelector("#ct");
var i = 1;

slider.onmouseover = slider.onclick = function(e){
   if(e.type == "click" && e.target.tagName == "INPUT"){
      i = e.target.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
   }
   clearInterval(timer);
}

window.onload = slider.onmouseleave = function(){
   timer = setInterval(Move,3000); //change img in 3 sec
}

function Move(){  
   i = (i%3)+1; // 4 is the Number of image in slider
   document.getElementById('t'+i).checked = true;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:#0066FF;}

#ct{ 
 position:relative; 
 width:400px; 
 height:220px; 
 margin:auto; 
 border:2px solid #000; 
 overflow:hidden;
}
input{ display:none;}

.img_s{ position:absolute; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 z-index:-1; 
 font-size:25px;
 text-align:center;
}

.im1, .im2, .im3{ position:relative; width:400px; 
 height:225px;
}

.pre, .nxt{ position:absolute;
 width:12%;
 height:100%;
 top:0;
 background:rgba(88,88,88,.4);
 z-index:99;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:30px;
}
p{ position:relative; top:50px;
}
.pre{ left:0; 
}
.nxt{ right:0; 
}
.cr{ width:100%;
 height:11px;
 bottom:12px;
 position:absolute;
 text-align:center;
 z-index:99;
}
.dts{ position: relative; 
 display: inline-block;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
 
#t1:checked ~ #one,
#t2:checked ~ #two,
#t3:checked ~ #three{
 z-index:99; transition:all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
Clique nas imagens:
<br>
<div id="ct">
   <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t1" checked/>
   <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t2"/>
   <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="t3"/>

   <div class="img_s" id="one">
      <div class="im1" style="background-color: #FFF;">01-IMG</div>
      <label for="t3" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
      <label for="t2" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
   </div>

   <div class="img_s" id="two">
      <div class="im2" style="background-color:#0C3;">02-IMG</div>
      <label for="t1" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
      <label for="t3" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
   </div>

   <div class="img_s" id="three">
      <div class="im3" style="background-color:#F63;">03-IMG</div>
      <label for="t2" class="pre"><p>&#10094;</p></label>
      <label for="t1" class="nxt"><p>&#10095;</p></label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No do outro usuario acima eu fiquei em duvida, sobre a quantidade de checagem que ele mudou, mas vc deixou o numero de checagens, não sei se o dele é o numero de checagens mesmo ou se é infinita, mas o seu ficou bem fluído e bem mais indicado

Comment: Ajustei o código, tinha uns bugs ainda

Comment: Na outra resposta, se vc clicar em cima da seta e deixar o mouse parado, o slide irá continuar. É porque ele não tratou do click que eu citei na minha resposta: "_inclusive precisará parar a transição no clique nas setas porque ao clicar o evento mouseleave é chamado_"

Comment: Testei e — aparentemente — está *ok*. Cliquei sobre ambas setas e aguardei alguns segundos (sem mover o *mouse*), porém a imagem não mudou. Aliás, ambos os códigos funcionam da mesma forma; ambos mudam a imagem após o clique na seta (desde que retire o *mouse* da área do *slider*).

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Verdade! Ao clicar na seta e manter o mouse sobre o elemento o slide fica pausado.

Comment: Eu estava achando estranho, porque o outro funcionava da mesma forma e a transição fazia a função de pausar e continuar, só que o mudam um do outro é o numero de checagens um possui e o outro não precisa, que se torna opcional, ambos resolveram